# Potential of a quadrupole

Tags: tensors

I have a function of potential created by a quadrupole `Q`

```
φ = (Subscript[Q, αβ] x^α x^b)/(2 r^5)
```

How can I derive the electric field without going to a concrete expression for `Q`? In other words, how can I tell to Mathematica that `Q` is a symmetric tensor so that it can process the convolution properly? Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you talking about taking the gradient? Is this a two dimensional or three dimensional problem?

Comment: Exactly, I am talking about taking the gradient in 3D and it can be done on the paper without too much effort. But I would like Mathematica to do it for me, and it can give me the same result only if it knows, that Q is a symmetric tensor. I am wondering how I can tell it to Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do. The quadrupole tensor is not only symmetric, but also traceless. Therefore, you'll need the following simple steps:

```
Clear[Q, R]

MatrixForm[ Q = {{Q11, Q12, Q13}, {Q12, Q22, Q23}, {Q13, Q23, -Q11 - Q22}}]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{Q11} & \text{Q12} & \text{Q13} \\
>  \text{Q12} & \text{Q22} & \text{Q23} \\
>  \text{Q13} & \text{Q23} & -\text{Q11}-\text{Q22} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

This is a starting point for the most general quadrupole tensor. The rest is done like this:

```
r = {x, y, z};

ϕ = r.Q.r/(2 (r.r)^(5/2));

e = FullSimplify[Grad[ϕ, r] /. x^2 -> (R^2 - y^2 - z^2), R > 0];

MatrixForm[e]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \frac{\text{Q11} x \left(2 R^2-5 x^2+5 z^2\right)+2 \text{Q12} y \left(R^2-5
>    x^2\right)+2 \text{Q13} R^2 z-10 \text{Q13} x^2 z-5 \text{Q22} x y^2+5 \text{Q22} x
>    z^2-10 \text{Q23} x y z}{2 R^7} \\
>  \frac{-5 \text{Q11} x^2 y+5 \text{Q11} y z^2+2 \text{Q12} x \left(R^2-5 y^2\right)-10
>    \text{Q13} x y z+\text{Q22} y \left(2 R^2-5 y^2+5 z^2\right)+2 \text{Q23} R^2 z-10
>    \text{Q23} y^2 z}{2 R^7} \\
>  \frac{z \left(-2 \text{Q11} R^2-5 \text{Q11} x^2+5 \text{Q11} z^2-10 \text{Q12} x y-2
>    \text{Q22} R^2-5 \text{Q22} y^2+5 \text{Q22} z^2\right)+2 \text{Q13} x \left(R^2-5
>    z^2\right)+2 \text{Q23} y \left(R^2-5 z^2\right)}{2 R^7} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

In the last step, I simplified the result of the gradient by introducing a symbolic variable `R` representing the radial distance. It is different from the vector `r`. With `R`, the expression becomes shorter and more readable, as in @Alexei Boulbitch's answer. My result is shorter because I also used the property $\text{Tr}(Q) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

This is the radius-vector:

```
R = Sqrt[Sum[(Subscript[x, a])^2, {a, 1, 3}]];
```

According to the definition in L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifschitz, Klassische Feldtheorie. (Akademie Verlag, Berlin, 1981) §41 the potential of a quadrupole is as follows (differing from your expression):

```
U1 = Sum[Subscript[Q, a, b]*D[R, Subscript[x, a], Subscript[x, b]], {a,1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]
```

Here I take the symmetry of the quadrupol tensor (Qab=Qba) into account:

```
U=U1/. {Subscript[Q, 2, 1] -> Subscript[Q, 1, 2], 
  Subscript[Q, 3, 1] -> Subscript[Q, 1, 3], 
  Subscript[Q, 3, 2] -> Subscript[Q, 2, 3]}// Simplify
```

It is easier to place an image of the result here,

[image]

while the Mma expression, you can obtain by evaluation. Now taking the gradient one gets the electric field intensity, e:

```
e = -Grad[U, {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3]}, 
"Cartesian"] // Simplify
```

This gives a vector, a rather long expression to show it here.

You might alternatively define its components as follows:

```
Subscript[e, i_] := -D[U, Subscript[x, i]] // Simplify
```

Then, say, the x-component will be given by evaluation of

```
Subscript[e, 1]
```

yielding the following:

[image]

One may also want to return to traditional notations. Then

```
  Subscript[e, 1] /. {\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\), \(2\)] + 
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) -> r^2, 
   Subscript[x, 1] -> x, Subscript[x, 2] -> y, Subscript[x, 3] -> z} //Simplify[#, r > 0] &
```

yielding this:

[image]

Have fun!